# $y=k^x$ when $k$ is negative

Tags: exponential-function

Hi I am learning about exponential functions and it points out that $k$ must be positive in $y=k^x$. I was wondering what would happen if $k$ is negative as I have drawn a rough copy of the graph and it seems quite interesting. Is it a valid graph and can anyone draw a stimulation of it please as I can't find an online graph sketcher that will draw it. Would $y=(-1)^x$ be almost like a oscillating wave?? Also can $k=0$ ? I'm just curious if this sort of graph exists. Thanks

Comment: The outputs will only be real for certain values of x. For instance, it’s percectly valid to consider your function for integer values of x, but what happens when x is, say, 1/2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets consider $k^x$ when x is an integer and $k<1$.

Provided $x$ is an integer $x \in \mathbb{I}$ we have no issues.

Taking for example $k = -2$  we have:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
  x&\text{}&k^x\\
  \hline
  3&(-2)^3&-8\\
  2&(-2)^2&4\\
  1&(-2)^1&-2\\
  0&(-2)^0&1\\
  -1&\dfrac{1}{(-2)^1}&-\dfrac{1}{2}\\
  -2&\dfrac{1}{(-2)^2}&\dfrac{1}{4}\\
  -3&\dfrac{1}{(-2)^3}&-\dfrac{1}{8}
\end{array}
 $$

Now consider $x = \dfrac{1}{2}$, and $k^x = \sqrt{-2} = ?$

We can solve this with complex numbers $k^x = i \cdot \sqrt{2}$

Where $i = \sqrt{-1}$

Similarly $x = -\dfrac{1}{2}$, and $k^x = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{-2}} = - \dfrac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$

But our solutions are not real numbers any more $k^x \notin \mathbb{R}$

When $ k \lt 0$ we do not have real solutions for all x

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that $k^x$ is defined as $\exp(x\log(k))$ (at least if $x$ is not rational), which is problematic for negative $k$. Even if you restrict yourself to rational $x$, you need to explain what $k^{1/2} = \sqrt{k}$ is (and similarly for higher roots). It is only unproblematic for integer $x$.

Comment: okay so is the graph not possible because you can't sqr root a negative number?

Comment: Do you really mean "The problem is that $k^x$ is **defined** as $\exp(x\log(k))$"? Perhaps you mean "is equal to"?

Comment: @yt. Yes, basically. And things get worse if you take $x$ irrational.

Comment: @user1729 How would you define $k^x$ for $x$ irrational?

Comment: I don't know. But I also do not know how to define $e^x$ for $x$ irrational.

Comment: @user1729 $e^x = \exp(x)$ is defined by the exponential series for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand. I didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the real plane, it doesn’t make sense for any $x$ that is not an odd integer.

However, if you were to draw it on an Agrand diagram, which is the complex plane, you’ll get a unit circle centered at the origin.

You can write $-1=e^{i\pi}$, so $(-1)^x=e^{i\pi x}$. This traces out the unit circle for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

For negative $k$, you’ll get a spiral that spirals out anti-clockwise.